# how to access integer variable from GameScene to ViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a gamecenter button that I added to my GameViewController from the storyboard. I need to use the highscore variable created in my GameScene as my highscore on the leader board.

```
let highscore = self.gameScene.highscore

saveHighScore(number: highscore)
```

I keep getting zero as my score. What do I do?

Comment: You have not provided nearly enough information.

Comment: Can you describe or show (with code) where the `GameScene` is in relation to the `GameViewController` and the "leader board" as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just had to use

saveHighScore(number: highscoreDefault.value(forKey: "highscore") as! NSInteger!)

where I had my highscore saved in the phone storage